# Android Collections.min NoSuchElementException

Tags: javascript, android, list, arraylist, collections

Right now, I have a program that contains this piece of code:

```
if(Highest6.y == 0){
    if(G.y == Collections.min(YUpper) && !notdone){     Highest6 = G;    YUpper.remove(Integer.valueOf(G.y));   notdone = true;}
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:
[image]

The most interesting thing that I have identical snippets, which appear in different `HighestX.y` statements(I have six of them). And  this error occurs only in the last one. Anybody knows why this keeps happening? Thanks in advance.

Here's code for my list:

```
 List<Integer> YPoint = new java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList(A.y, B.y, C.y, D.y, E.y, F.y, G.y, K.y, Q.y, L.y, M.y, N.y));
        List<Integer> YUpper = new java.util.ArrayList(Arrays.asList());
int Classified = 0;
    int Highest = 0;


    while(Classified != 6){
        Highest = Collections.min(YPoint);
        YPoint.remove(Integer.valueOf(Highest));
        YUpper.add(Integer.valueOf(Highest));
        Classified++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your collection is empty. From the [documentation of Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html%23min(java.util.Collection)) min returns:

> NoSuchElementException - if the collection is empty

That is: your `yUpper` Arraylist is empty:

```
Collections.min(YUpper)
```

And it's empty because you never enter that while loop:

```
    while(Classified != 6){
```

As `classified` is 0

*Style note*: use camelCase for variables & methods. That's the way Java code is meant to be written. Not `MyVar` but `myVar`. It's easier to read to Java people.

Comment: You're right. How couldn't I see this before? Thanks.